# Discord.js: Add input field to slash command

Tags: input, discord.js, command, slash

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0moIW.png)

Hey guys,
can anyone tell me how to add such an input field to a slash command in Discord.js (v.14)?
Example above.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the official DJS guide on Slash Commands?

Comment: Hello, just to help you familiarise with StackOverflow, we do not spoon feed here. You are simply in the wrong place and did not seem to read how to ask a question. Please refer to the side panel when posting a question to ensure that you get the correct answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the discord.js doc [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommand?scrollTo=options)
When you create a command, you have just to set the options parameters :

```js
client.application.commands.create({
    type: "CHAT_INPUT",
    name: "mycommand",
    description: "My awesome command",
    options: [
        {
            type: "STRING",
            name: "firstparameter",
            description: "My first parameter",
            required: true
        }
    ]
});
```